# Re-render component ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to react and creating some demo app I want to render my header component on the login user but somehow my app doesn’t re-render the app.js component when I login with the user

here is my app.js

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Header user={localStorage.getItem("user")} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
       </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
  );
}
```

note: I am saving my user in localStorage when I login into the app, please let me know if you need more info

Comment: You don't seem to bee updatinng the user state to cause a re-render of the App component.

Comment: sorry for that i am not using any user state for now @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: So I imagine that when user is logged on you are saving user into localStorage but Header will be not updated with new value correct?

Comment: You neeed to cause a re-render of the App component regardless of whether you use user state or not so that Header takes in the updated data after login

Comment: yes @GiovanniEsposito i want to user different header options on basis of this user

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri how can i re-render app component and is this best practice to re-render app component?

Comment: You can maintain the user data in state of App component and pass on the function to update user as props to the login component, once the user is logged in, call the function to update the user state. This will cause App component to rerender and subsequently update Header component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can you please share any code snippets so that i can get good idea about how to do that

Comment: You could force a re-render BUT it's really bad solution. Your question is a little bit long to answer because involves a `general state manager`. Why don't you take a look at https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started. If I have time I will post an answer. Ciao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the user data in state of App component and pass on the function to update user as props to the login component, once the user is logged in, call the function to update the user state. This will cause App component to rerender and subsequently update Header component.

Below is a sample implementation of how you can possible structure and write your code

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Header user={user} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage setUser={setUser}/>
          </Route>
       </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
  );
}

function Login(props) {
   ...
   onUserLogin=() => {
     // Below is a mock implementation of a API service. You can use fetch or axios 
     Api.loginUser({...you params go here}).then(user => {
         props.setUser(user); // This updates the parent component with user state
     })

   }
   ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`localStorage` doesn't trigger a re-render in React.

You must have a global store to save the `user` data.

Comment: hi @Carlos  i am familiar with only localStorage and sessionStorage what is global store and how can i save user data into it